# No ID assigned to objects when created in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Class in my models.py named Order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='customer_name',
    )
    order_individual_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    order_total_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_name
```

In my views.py I create a new instance of order when a button is pressed

```
def ordering(request):
    latest_order = Order.objects.all()
    menu = Menu.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            menu_instance = request.POST.get('add')
            if menu_instance:
                get_order = Menu.objects.get(id=menu_instance)
                get_price = get_order.Menu_price
                new_order = Order.objects.create(customer_name=request.user, 
                order_name=get_order, order_individual_price=get_price)

                return redirect('shop-ordering')
            order_instance = request.POST.get('delete')

        else:
           messages.info(request, f'Please Sign In First')
           return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'shop/ordering.html', {'title':'Ordering', 'latest_order': 
    latest_order, 'menu':menu})
```

Trying to access the ID through the shell by this command

```
>>> from shop.models import Menu, Order
>>> Order.objects.get(id=1)
```

But Instead, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/alan/Desktop/FRIENDS_CAFE_DJANGO/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alan/Desktop/FRIENDS_CAFE_DJANGO/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
shop.models.Order.DoesNotExist: Order matching query does not exist.
```

However, when I run `Order.objects.all()` it gives me back the objects

```
>>> Order.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Order: test1>, <Order: test2>]>
```

I didn't touch any of the **init** files and since django creates the ID automatically, I'm really confused on why its not assigning each order a ID.

Comment: Can you share where you try to get the ID of the object?

Comment: Okay, so without testing your code, I'd say that the object is not being created at all because when you attempt to create it, you pass to `order_name` field a `Menu` instance instead of a string (which is what it expects)

Comment: Have you done with migrations part?

Comment: I frogot to mention that doing a Order.objects.all() gives me all of the objects but I just cant access any of them. I passed in the Menu instance into order_name because I only want the name of the that instance which it does give me in the html.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the ID is exactly `1`? Try running `Order.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)` to see the IDs of the objects in the database.

Comment: WHOA, it returns 27 and 28 which correspond to the objects. How does this work? Edit: Did some googling and realized that this is the default behavior. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command to see the ID of your current Order objects. If Order objects exist and your query is failing is because there is not an Order object with pk=1.

```
Order.objects.all().values('id')
```